# WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 Service Provider registration fails

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure a service provider and I am expecting to see configuration steps like Inbound Authentication Configuration but when I give a service provider name and hit register, nothing happens. All I see is an empty page just with the main pane on the left. When I click List from the left pane I can see the provider I added but when I try to edit it same thing happens. Also same thing when I try to add an Identity Provider but instead when I click the List on the Identity Providers menu, I can click on resident ıdentity Provider and then I can see a configuration menu. 
I am using WSO Identity Server 5.1.0. on Windows 7 with JAVA SDK 1.8.0_60.

Comment: Can you share the logs you get when you get this failure? You can find the logs at <IS_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log

Comment: The problem has solved it self. I deleted the first service provider and added a new one. Then i restarted the WSO2 server and suddendly i could see the newly registered service provider in the console:)